# Issue when installing anything from terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I'm having trouble installing anything through the terminal, I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 15.10. After typing in my password I get this message

```
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

[image: Picture]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the automated update search to finish. It will release the lock, and you can install just fine after it.